# Empty list in Haskell is not running in function even though I have a base case checking for empty lists

Tags: haskell, quicksort, empty-list

```
    -- quick sort a list in Haskell
qsort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]  
-- check to see if the list is empty
qsort [] = []
-- if the list is  not empty split the list by the head/first element and the rest of the list...
qsort (x:xs) = 
  -- create one list for the smaller elements in the list that will use quick sort recursively
  let small = qsort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
      --create one list for the larger elements in the list that will use quick sort recursively
      big = qsort [a | a <- xs, a > x]
  -- return the combined lists of the smaller elements list with the original head of the list with the bigger elements list
  in small ++ [x] ++ big

list1 = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 2, 7, 4]
list2 = [5, 6, 2, 3, 6, 0, 3, 9, 8, 0]
liste = []
list3 = [-4, 5, -8, 0, -3, 2 ,4]

main:: IO ()

main = 
  do
    print(qsort list1)
    print(qsort list2)
    print(qsort list3)
    print(qsort liste)
```

The error I keep getting is:

> ```
> Main.hs:29:11: error:
> • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘qsort’
>   prevents the constraint ‘(Ord a0)’ from being solved.
>   Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
>   These potential instances exist:
>     instance Ord Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
>     instance Ord Integer
>       -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.3.0:GHC.Integer.Type’
>     instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Maybe’
>     ...plus 22 others
>     ...plus four instances involving out-of-scope types
>     (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
> • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(qsort liste)’
>   In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (qsort liste)
>   In the expression:
>     do print (qsort list1)
>        print (qsort list2)
>        print (qsort list3)
>        print (qsort liste)    | 29 |     print(qsort liste)    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^ Failed, no modules loaded.   <interactive>:1:1: error:
> • Variable not in scope: main
> • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
> ```

Comment: `print(qsort liste)` is a problem, since it is unclear what the type of the elements should be.

Comment: Provide a type to `liste` -- is that an empty list of `Int`? Of `Char`?  This is needed since `qsort` needs to access the comparison operator. (It actually does not need that since the list is empty so no comparison is done, but the type still requires `Ord`, so GHC has to provide that.)

Comment: Okay I see, I had to define liste as `liste :: [Integer]
                                                        liste = []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type needs to be disambiguated with an explicit signature:

```
liste :: [Integer]
liste = []
list1 = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 2, 7, 4]
list2 = [5, 6, 2, 3, 6, 0, 3, 9, 8, 0]
list3 = [-4, 5, -8, 0, -3, 2 ,4]
```

Comment: I'd recommend also applying the signature to the other lists, i.e. `list1, list2, list3, liste :: [Integer]`. But do consider if `Integer` is actually the type you want – in doubt, you can keep it more general with `:: Num a => [a]`.